# Scrollviewer automatically stops

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-phone-7

I have horizontal scrollviewer in my app. I would like that when I swipe screen to scroll it stops automatically in points that I had set. Something like gallery in android, you may swipe only one photo per one swipe. I don't know if all of my pages (like photos) must be on one big page (5000px width), or I have to do each page separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 3-tab `Pivot` and load next/prev image after user swipe left or right a `Pivot`

Comment: or use a `Panorama` without header to see next image after scroll a half of an image